# Java inheritance casting runtime error vs compiler error

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, compiler-errors, runtime-error

### The Problem

Consider the code below. `B` inherits from `A`, and none of them inherit from `String`.

I'd like to know the answers to the following questions:

1. why does the first first cast, `B b1 = (B) a1;`, produce a runtime error?
2. why does the first second cast, `String b1 = (String) a1;`, produce a compilation error?
3. Why is there a difference? Why doesn't the compiler see the problem in the first case?

### The Code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        B b1 = (B) a1;
        
        String b1 = (String) a1;
    }

}
```

with class `A`:

```
public class A {}
```

and class `B`:

```
public class B extends A {}
```

Comment: @AndyTurner why can the compiler deal with statements such as `B b1 = new A();` but not with case "1" in  the question?

Comment: Because the compiler knows that an expression of type `A` is not compatible in an assignment context with a variable of type `B`. You can cast: `B b1 = (B) new A();`; but that will obviously fail at runtime.

Comment: @AndyTurner so in this simple case it is able to deduce `new A()` is of type `A`, but  in the 1st case it is unable to figure out what `a1` is? If it is caught in runtime why can't it be caught in compilation, or is this just an implementation choice not to implement this error catching process?

Comment: `new A()` is an expression of type `A`. You can only assign expressions of type `B` (or a subtype) to a variable of type `B`.

Comment: @AndyTurner but `a1 = new A();` so `a1` is `new A()` so it "is an expression `A`" too, no?

Comment: Yes. `a1` is a variable of type `A`, so you can only assign expressions of type `A` (or a subtype) to it. `b1` (the first one) is a variable of type `B`, so you can only assign expressions of type `B` (or a subtype) to it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229788/discussion-between-ariel-yael-and-andy-turner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable of type A could have been assigned an instance of B, because a B *is an* A. Eg a Dog is an Animal, so a box labelled “Animal” could contain a dog.

But a variable of type A cannot have been assigned a String. Eg A box labelled “Animal” will not contain a Brick.

You may be asking yourself why the compiler doesn’t complain when we can see that the code will clearly fail - there’s no way the variable is a B; it’s an A!

The compiler looks only at the *type* of the variable when making its checks. It doesn’t examine what code came before. Although your example is simple, checking what a variable actually contains would be an impossible task in the general case.

Comment: As I asked other people who answered here,  why why does `B b1 = new A();` produce compilation error but `A a1 = new A();B b1 = (B) a1;` gives a runtime error? If I understand your explanation at the last paragraph its because the 2nd time we have two lines, and when reading the 2nd line (`B b1 = (B) a1;`) the compiler assumes nothing about `a1` so it doesn't know its of type `A` actually?

Comment: @ArielYael exactly. The compiler only checks each line of code in isolation and bases all its checks on the declared types of the variables/constants involved (not on what the actual type may be, even if there is only one code path before the line being checked).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. why does the first first cast, B b1 = (B) a1;, produce a runtime error?

Variables of type `A` can store instances of `B`. However, not all instances of `A` are instances of `B`.

An `A` is not a `B`, but a `B` is an `A`. (Like, not all animals are dogs, but dogs are animals).

> 2. why does the first second cast, String b1 = (String) a1;, produce a compilation error?

`A` is not a supertype of `String`, and `String` is not a supertype of `B`.

> 3. Why is there a difference? Why doesn't the compiler see the problem in the first case?

Because variables of type `A` can store instances of `B`; but variables of type `A` can never store instances of `String`.

Answer (score 1):

A variable of type `A` could in fact be of type `B` as B extends A. But a variable of type `A` can never be of type `String`. That's why the compiler can catch the cast to `String`, but not the cast to `B`.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the first first cast, B b1 = (B) a1;, produce a runtime error?

Because `a1` is an instance of `A`, but is not compatible with `B`. Specifically, `new A()` creates an object that is not compatible with subclasses of `A`. If the runtime class (i.e., the class with which `new` was called) of the object is not the same as or a subclass of the target class, casting to that target class will fail at runtime. This is simply because the child class has nothing to do with that object.

> why does the first second cast, String b1 = (String) a1;, produce a compilation error?

Even if the actual casting happens at runtime, the compiler performs type checks and prevents pointless operations like this. For this scenario, casting an `A` object to `String` is nonsense and the compiler can detect it: there is no relationship between `String` and `A`, and the compiler knows what class is a child of what other class. The compiler knows that there is no way in Java for `a1` to be an instance of `String` or of a subclass of `String`, and that's because `String` is not a parent of `A`, the declared type of `a1`. There are exceptions to this, such as when the cast is begin made to an interface.

> Why is there a difference? Why doesn't the compiler see the problem in the first case?

The compiler only validates type casts based on static types (the type of the variable or of the expression). It doesn't look at the runtime class, which of course isn't available until runtime when the object is actually created. When it can determine with certainty that the cast can't possibly be valid (such as in the second case), it will fail. In the first case, casting from `A` to `B` passes compilation because the declared types are compatible (i.e., an `A` object can possibly be an instance of `B`, and the compiler leaves it for the runtime to check the actual object). In the second case, the compiler knows that an `A` object can never be an instance of `String` (because `String` is nowhere in `A`'s type hierarchy, and this won't change at runtime)

Comment: Could you explain please why why does `B b1 = new A();` produce compilation error but `A a1 = new A();B b1 = (B) a1;` gives a runtime error?

Comment: @ArielYael the first one simply fails because you can't store an A in a B variable. It's like Java is enforcing that all fruits are not apples. If the variable is to hold an apple, the compiler knows that it should not let you put any fruit in it. The second one passes compilation because a1 is created to hold a fruit, and the compiler doesn't care what kind of fruit you actually put in a1. The problem is that new A() is not compatible with B. So the compiler is fine as an A could be a B. But at runtime, it's known that the object has nothing to do with class B, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

The class hierarchy diagram for the class A would be:

Object -> A -> B (Note that every class extends Object)

B b1 = (B) a1;

The above line compiles because B extends A and hence the compiler sees it as a valid downcast. The java compiler only checks whether it is possible for an object of type A to be of type B, by checking the class hierarchy of B (whether B extends A directly or indirectly). It doesn't check the actual type of the object A at this point. It wasn't implemented this way since it would add a lot of complexity in the compiler. Also if an object is being downcast (to call some specific sub class method perhaps), then the responsibility is on the programmer to be aware of the specific type of the object. In this example since a1 can't be cast to type B, it will be detected by the JVM at runtime.

String b1 = (String) a1;

In this case, the class String is nowhere in the class hierarchy diagram of A. Therefore it can be detected at compile time that this is an invalid cast.